# Uncaught ReferenceError: spanArray is not defined

Tags: javascript

I want to make a button to start the onclick to make the random numbers keep running,(use

1. or 2. to call) but if I press it , the error message shows that "Uncaught

ReferenceError: spanArray is not defined"  but above the number is still running, I cannot

understand where is the wrong place.

PS But if I use 3 it work normally.

Thx!

thx complete code I try  by 3 is http://jsfiddle.net/eVyjC/

```
function computeRandom(){
// skip code: have used loop to create six spans already
var spanArray = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
//1.document.write("<input type =  button  value = 'start' onclick = \"passKeepMove(value,spanArray) \"  name = button1>");
//2.document.write("<input type =  button  value = 'start' onclick =  \"setInterval(function(){keepMove(value,spanArray);}, 10) \"  name = button1>");
//3.setInterval(function(){keepMove(value,spanArray);}, 10) ;
   }


function keepMove(val,sp){//call by pointer 

    var index = parseInt(Math.random()*43);//set a increment to avoid repeatition

    for( i = 0; i < sp.length; i++){
    sp[i].innerHTML = val[i+index];
    }
}


function passKeepMove(v,s){
    setInterval(function(){keepMove(v, s);}, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `var` in front of `var spanArray` is making `spanArray` a local variable. So you can not access it outside of `computeRandom`'s function scope.

You need to make it global or come up with a better design so you do not need global variables.

Comment: But why I use setInterval(function(){keepMove(value,spanArray);}, 10) in the computeRandom it works fine?

Comment: As I only use them as arguments to call function in the computeRandom, I think that it doesn't matter local or global?

Comment: I am just a rookie, so above are only my opinions. If it is wrong, please tell me.Thx.

Comment: Because when you create the `setInterval` the variable spanArray is in the same scope.

Comment: What I don't know is that I call function by document.write which are in the computeRandom by 1. and 2., why they cannot be see? Isn't they are in the same scope?

Comment: Because when they are called, it is not in scope. It is looking for the variable from window, not that function. It would be better to create the elements with createElement, appendChild and add the onclick.